# PHP, $_SESSION, iFrame, Not saving session inside iFrame, but does outside of iFrame

Tags: php, session, iframe

I am developing a Shopify App using PHP and Heroku. The PHP App loads inside of an iFrame within the Shopify domain (https://store-name.myshopify.com)

Example

```
<iframe title="App Name" src="https://my-php-app.herokuapp.com/?hmac=****locale=en-US&session=******&store-name.myshopify.com&timestamp=1607181510" name="app-iframe" context="Main" style="position: relative; border: none; width: 100%; flex: 1 1 0%; display: flex;"></iframe>
```

**Problem**

The $_SESSION is not staying intact on a page refresh inside of an iframe, but the exact same code works perfectly outside of an iframe.

**Outside of iFrame**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id()."<br>";
if(!$_SESSION['test']) $_SESSION['test'] = array();
$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

The results look like this after 3 page refreshes...

```
1ko6l3mqre570jtvsuh44tcuc2p0dhfs
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1607181723
            [1] => 1607181725
            [2] => 1607181726
        )

)
```

This is correct... however, loading this same PHP code inside of an iframe does not work...

**Inside of iFrame**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id()."<br>";
if(!$_SESSION['test']) $_SESSION['test'] = array();
$_SESSION['test'][] = time();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

Incorrect results...

```
70o3mj3v5t4cca7d477flfjubd7tu0rc
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1607181700
        )

)
```

Even after 3+ page refreshes, it just overwrites the first key, rather than adding to the array...
Also the SESSION ID constantly refreshes.

I have done extensive research on this problem for a few days without finding any solutions.

I'm using Chrome Version 87

**EDIT**

Thanks to Didier for pointing me in the right direction.

Solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539472/chrome-not-keeping-my-session-vars-when-coming-from-3rd-party-iframe-but-works)

```
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 'true');
session_start();
```

Comment: What is the samesite value of your session cookie? [Maybe it's the same problem they had here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539472/chrome-not-keeping-my-session-vars-when-coming-from-3rd-party-iframe-but-works)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome not keeping my \_SESSION vars when coming from 3rd-party IFRAME but works perfectly when accessed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539472/chrome-not-keeping-my-session-vars-when-coming-from-3rd-party-iframe-but-works)